# Z3 in C#, Only getting 1 result

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, z3, smt

I am using z3 in visual studio and I want to do a simple check with the following 
x > 3
After I run my code, I only get one result back in my model. Why do I only get one result back and how would I do model completion in C#?

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Z3 is a satisfiability solver (the S in SMT), i.e., it checks whether there is 1 assignment that satisfies the formula. It can compute sets of solutions in some special cases and if the problems are set up the right way, but without further details I can't tell whether any of this would apply to your problem.

Of course, after getting one satisfying assignment you can add a new constraint that forces the assignment you just got is excluded and then get a new assignment.